# Three.js - strange shading behaviour

Tags: three.js, shadow

Where does the vertical shadow on the left cube come from?

https://jsfiddle.net/yz0sfr35/

```
//I'm using:
renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.BasicShadowMap;
```

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about the red surface on the left(mirror) box?

Comment: Yes. The to the left is a red box, that receives shadow from the box in the middle. Light is on the top right.

Comment: The red is not a shadow it's the background. Bellow the middle box's reflection you can see the "floor" and after it ends the "void" is colored red - box's color.

Comment: The red is the color of the left box. Black is the shadow. The bottom 2/3 of the left box is in shadow from the middle box. I don't understand where does the black square on the upper third of the left box come from (check the picture above) .

Comment: Hmm interesting it seems to disappear if you move the cub1 by 1px on the either x or y axis.

Comment: You think the strange black square on the left box is the reflection of the middle box?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155139/discussion-between-mihailo-and-croraf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is pixelation in your shadows due to the fact that your shadow camera frustum is orders-of-magnitude larger than your scene.

[image: screenshot of frustum]

One solution in your case is to reduce the angle of your spotlight:

```
light.angle = Math.PI / 180;
```

Keep your shadow frustums tight around your scene for quality shadows.

https://jsfiddle.net/yz0sfr35/2/

three.js r.87